# make a userform as a layer for all other userforms for this project

Tags: vba, transparency, userform

I have a code which can ccontrol transparent of a userform so, I want to make a fake userform which has the logo for the company and make it transparent to all other userform the problem is how can show 2 userforms at same time and make the fake userform as a layer in the front of other userform and be able to work with the behind userform, I hope I explain my point well

this is a photo of what I want to do:

[image]

this is the code for userform transparent

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow _
    Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong _
    Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong _
    Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes _
    Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal crey As Byte, ByVal bAlpha As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20)
Private Const WS_EX_LAYERED = &H80000
Private Const LWA_ALPHA = &H2&

Public hWnd As Long

Sub MakeTransparent(frm As Object, TransparentValue As Integer)

Dim bytOpacity As Byte

'Control the opacity setting. bytOpacity = TransparentValue

hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", frm.Caption)
Call SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) Or WS_EX_LAYERED)
Call SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, bytOpacity, LWA_ALPHA)

End Sub
```

the following code I put it in the second userform which I have work on it and it will be behind the first userform which it has the transparent logo, I got an error when I run the code but it's displayed after error message like the screenshot which I attached up

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.Show vbModeless
UserForm1.Top = Me.Top + 20
UserForm1.Left = Me.Left + 20
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

If you want to ask me for any more explain i am waiting for discuss
thank you in advance for support

this is the code what I talked about in my comment

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
'// Constants for SetWindowPos hWndInsertAfter Parameter
'Private Const HWND_TOP = 0
'Private Const HWND_BOTTOM = 1
Private Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
'// Constants for SetWindowPos wFlags Parameter
Private Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
'Private Const SWP_NOCOPYBITS = &H100
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
'Private Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = &H200
'Private Const SWP_NOREDRAW = &H8
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
Private Function OnTop(bOnTop As Boolean) As Boolean
 Dim hwnd As Long

 '// Find the Window using it's caption - Make sure the
 '// caption is reasonably unique

 hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, UserForm1.Caption)
 If hwnd > 0 Then
 If bOnTop Then
 OnTop = CBool(SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
 SWP_NOACTIVATE Or _
 SWP_SHOWWINDOW Or _
 SWP_NOMOVE Or _
 SWP_NOSIZE))
 Else
 OnTop = CBool(SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
 SWP_NOACTIVATE Or _
 SWP_SHOWWINDOW Or _
 SWP_NOMOVE Or _
 SWP_NOSIZE))
 End If
 Else
 OnTop = False
 End If

End Function
```

Comment: after searching I find that piece below, I tried it in many ways and modified it many times but unfortunately, no avail

Comment: What was the error you received?  It would be great if you added it to your question.

Comment: class module cannot assist in this predicament ?
I mean automate an userform to appear in front of any userform with this project be visible but disactive to let the other userform to be setfocus

Comment: You never told us what error you receive.  I would guess you get an error on this line:  `Me.Show vbModeless`.  The form is already in the process of being shown and you try showing it again.  Try taking this line out completely or moving it someplace else.

Comment: A more fundamental problem is the form with the logo.  Since this form is on top it has focus and therefore you cannot interact with the other form even though you can see the controls.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Brain for ur support, now I don't get errors but as u said I see the two userforms my logo is on the top but i cannot interact with the second userform, I can interact with the second userform when I move the logo userform in this time i can see the logo userform on the top and can work with the second userform. so, now I try to get positions for the objects on the second userform and make a macro when the user click this positions in the logo userform setfocus same object in the second userform. do U see this will help

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is impossible, just sometimes we need to change our way of thinking with more focus and try all possible tricks to circumvent the problem and cross the obstacle and give up the important for the most important, with your support and advice finally I reached what I was looking for.
I made the main userforms is the Layer and the logo is fixed in the background and I made the logo on an excel sheet with some modifications to the Excel sheet I reached this result on the attached screenshot below. I think it's not so bad and it works.
thank you again for stackoverflow team for your support 
[image]